# If i select one radiobutton and select path from dropdown it should show alert that particular path is not allowed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 radio buttons. If I select one radio button and select particular path from drop down which contains x string , it should show alert that please select other path. How can I do this using JavaScript or jQuery?

I have tried index Of function but it is showing alert for whatever drop down I am selecting. It should show alert when I select one radio button and select path which contains raw.

```js
var path = "/c/devops/java/raw";
if (document.getElementById('transaction3').checked) {
  var indexOfFirst = (path.indexOf('/raw') !== -1);
  alert("Renaming of files under Raw folder is not allowed!!!");
}
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you include the code you have problems with in your question. Both HTML and JS.

Comment: var path = "/c/devops/java/raw";
    if (document.getElementById('transaction3').checked ) {
     var indexOfFirst = (path.indexOf('/raw')!==-1);
      alert("Renaming of files under Raw folder is not allowed!!!");
   }

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58591171/edit) button to add the code into your question, it's unreadable if posted as a comment. And your HTML is still missing. If you are having troubles on how to structurize your question, [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a good ressource to start